# How to obtain the class binding of a method?

Tags: ruby, reflection, methods

Take

```rb
class A; def foo; end; end
class B < A; end
b = B.new          # => #<B:0x0000000243b8c0>
m = b.method :foo  # => #<Method: B(A)#foo>
m.owner            # => A
m.receiver         # => #<B:0x0000000243b8c0>
m.receiver.class   # => B
mm = m.unbind      # => #<UnboundMethod: B(A)#foo>
```

How can I get `B` from `mm` short of parsing the result of `mm.to_s`?

Comment: I knew it's your question before looking at your name :)

Comment: :-) Is that good or bad, @SergioTulentsev? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time looking at [proc.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/proc.c) and I don't think it is possible. `B` gets stored in `rclass` and as far as I can tell it is not accessible anywhere. You can see how it is used [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/proc.c#L1893), although I don't think that helps either.

May I ask why do you need to do that? Maybe there is another way to solve the general problem :)

Comment: I'm just exploring Ruby. I tried to take a method and use it in a different class and eventually got to this. So, no problem to solve, really. :-) Thanks!

Comment: I'm extremely happy to have thrown you in some C when you just started exploring Ruby. Welcome :)